# What are all of these W3C CSS Validation Warnings About?

Tags: css, validation

I have a website that was developed a few years back and I am trying to validate both the html and css using the W3C validation tools.

Aside from being told that W3C is obsolete and "don't worry about it", I would appreciate it if someone might explain to me all the warnings I see for such items as those listed below.

What I am curious to know is if I removed all of these would it have a significant adverse impact on my clients' websites? As my site was done years ago are these outdated?

-webkit-box-sizing is an unknown vendor extension

-moz-box-sizing is an unknown vendor extension

-webkit-border-radius is an unknown vendor extension

-moz-background-clip is an unknown vendor extension

-webkit-background-clip is an unknown vendor extension

-webkit-transition is an unknown vendor extension

-moz-transition is an unknown vendor extension

-o-transition is an unknown vendor extension

-webkit-box-sizing is an unknown vendor extension

-moz-box-sizing is an unknown vendor extension

-webkit-border-radius is an unknown vendor extension

-moz-background-clip is an unknown vendor extension

-webkit-background-clip is an unknown vendor extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These CSS vendor extensions (like most) are from a time when browsers were beginning to implement newer CSS3 rules and had different enough implementations that the non-prefixed properties weren't always accepted yet for compatibility reasons.

At this point, these look like they'd all be safe to remove from your CSS, but there's no particular benefit in doing so.

Comment: Thank you so much, and as for "there's no particular benefit to do so" let me kindly disagree. When you show a client and/or potential client look what you're getting, if they see a nice clean validation without any "warnings" and you having to explain the insignificance of the warnings, it goes a long way in the clients' eyes of the end product they have bought or are considering buying. Agree?

Comment: @TMHDesign I've been developing sites for a looong time and never heard of a client looking at HTML/CSS validation, so I don't agree. Especially because not all warnings are bad - in this case those vendor prefixes increase compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: Jon, I am not sure if you "get it". I have been developing sites longer than yourself. I am talking from a highly competitive sales environment such as which you probably do not compete in. When luring a client from a competitor, to show them a website developed by one's competitor (in this case you) and it has several hundred "warnings", and then to show them my flawless site will at the very least leave them wondering.